# Limit the number of simultaneous specific tasks in celery

Tags: python, celery, gpu

I have 2 tasks **taskA** and **taskB** which run using the GPU. They can both run on the GPU at the same time. But if celery decides to launch an additional instance, then I will have a crash (out of memory on the GPU).

I therefore would like to be able to have control over this (i.e. only allow **taskA** + **taskB**, or **taskB** + **taskB**, or **taskA** + **taskA** at the same time, but prevent for instance **taskA** + **taskA** + **taskB**).

How can I control this?

Answer (score 1):

You could limit the number of simultaneous tasks by using the [--concurrency](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/workers.html#concurrency) argument. Set this to 2 if you're using the same worker for both tasks or to 1 if you have two separate workers.